# Unit testing a Xamarin Forms Android specific code project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm running into an issue where I've done a Xamarin.Forms Application.

Currently, I'm trying to Unit test an Android Service.

So currently this means I've done the following at this point:

1. default Xamarin forms application with iOS project deleted
2. Basic Forms in the PCL created
3. Have styles created in Xamarin.Forms PCL
4. Have basic theme in Xamarin.Forms.Droid project

After doing that, I've created Xamarin UITest Android Project

Now, I've added a reference to the Xamarin Forms.Droid Project

Every time I launch the unit test, which has to run in the Android emulator, it fails to find the theme.

within the app.xml that resides in the PCL

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="BackgroundGlobal">#ff333333</Color>
        <Color x:Key="MidGradient">#ff0d0d0d</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BottomGradient">Black</Color>
        <Color x:Key="MenuTextColor">Azure</Color>
        <Style TargetType="ImageCell" x:Key="Clicky">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource  MenuTextColor}"/>
            <Setter Property="DetailColor" Value="Aqua"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

within the Xamarin.Forms.Droid Resource\Values\strings.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <resources>
        <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
        </style>

        <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
        <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
            <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
            <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
            <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
            <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
            <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
            <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
            <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
            <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
       </style>   
       <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
            <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
       </style>
   </resources>
```

I currently get the following:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error 
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/MainTheme').    Xamarin.Forms.Droid.Tests   C:\dev\git\example\Xamarin.Forms.Droid.Tests\obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml 9
```

Comment: Is the MainTheme exists in styles.xml? You can  see it in Resource -> values -> styles.xml.

Comment: Per request, I've updated the example showing the pcl styles and string/theme from Xamarin.Forms.Droid. Also, the Test project is default setup with Xamarin.Forms.Android and a resource / dependency to the test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/MainTheme').

`Resource\Values\strings.xml` just provides a text string with optional text style and formatting for your application. There are three types of resources that can provide a string for your application: `String`, `String Array` and `Quantity Strings(Plurals)`.

You should put your theme style in `Resource\Values\styles.xml` instead of  `styles.xml`, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9PMI.png).

For more information about `Style Resource`, you could read this [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I couldn't respond yesterday as quickly as I wanted because I wound up throwing my back out. Anyway. The `@style/MainTheme` was perfect! After looking at what I wrote, I found out, I did have things within the style.xml and not strings.xml. In either case, I decided to leave my question as is for other people who might need help too. Again, thank you VERY much for your help!