# xamarin android uitest theme style conflicts

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xunit

Recently I asked a question over trying to get my theme recognized within the android test project: [Unit testing a Xamarin Forms Android specific code project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000812/unit-testing-a-xamarin-forms-android-specific-code-project)

I'm not running into a conflict that shows up within `xunit` / `nunit` as the testing strategy. I feel like it's because the `FormsAppCompatActivity` with an older activity type, but I'm new to Xamarin and am unsure on how to approach this.

I get a lot of these type of errors:

`Attribute "layout_anchorGravity" already defined with incompatible format.`

The full list of the similar Attribute errors is:

```
 fabSize
 tabMode
 expandedTitleGravity
 layout_scollFlags
 layout_collapseMode
 collapsedTitleGravity
 tabGravity
 showDividers
 displayOptions
 showAsActions
 actionBarSize
```

finally I have the addition error:
`Found tag styles where item is expected`

```
//Within the Android Forms project, I have this inheritance:
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity {
    // typical code
}

//within the Android UITest project
public class MainActivity : Xunit.Runners.UI.RunnerActivity {
    // tests can be inside the main assembly
    AddTestAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    AddExecutionAssembly(typeof(ExtensibilityPointFactory).Assembly);
    // or in any reference assemblies           

    //AddTestAssembly(typeof(PortableTests).Assembly);
    // or in any assembly that you load (since JIT is available)

#if false
    // you can use the default or set your own custom writer (e.g. save to web site and tweet it ;-)
    Writer = new TcpTextWriter ("10.0.1.2", 16384);
    // start running the test suites as soon as the application is loaded
    AutoStart = true;
    // crash the application (to ensure it's ended) and return to springboard
    TerminateAfterExecution = true;
#endif
    // you cannot add more assemblies once calling base
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
 }
```